# Flutter Clipper fails with bool is null

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to clip a container decorated with an image but every second time I start the app it fails with

> I/flutter (23288): Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null
>
> I/flutter (23288): #0      _RenderCustomClip.clipper=(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1172:20)

[image]

```
Scaffold(
 body: ClipPath(
   clipper: RoundClip(),
   clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
   child: Container(
     height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
     width: double.infinity,
     margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 32.0),
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImageCache.of(context).getImageProviderByUrlLargestImagePossible('image-url'), fit: BoxFit.cover)
     )
    ),
  ),
),
```

My round clip is simple:

```
class RoundClip extends CustomClipper<Path> {
@override
Path getClip(Size size) {
var path = Path();

path.lineTo(48, 0);
path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width/8, size.height, size.width+100, size.height);

path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
path.close();

return path;
}

@override
bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
// TODO: implement shouldReclip
return null;
}
}
```

Comment: I followed a tutorial that did not include this part; and until now, it worked. :D

Answer (score 1):

For those who might be looking for the solution. 
Change your `shouldReclip()` method return value from `null` to any `bool` value `(say true or false)`.

Or simply replace your `shouldReclip() method` with below given code in the `clipper` class itself.

```
  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    // TODO: implement shouldReclip
    return true;
  }
```

[Link to the Source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20983#issuecomment-415715785)  for reference.